# Ruby << Hash << Array.include[incremented integer]

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following:

```
ht = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}

CertainParentClass.decendants.each do {|childrens|
  ht[childrens] << incremented_integer
}

$global_switch[0 ... ht.size] = false

def check_switch(object_class)
  return $global_switch[ht[object_class][0]]
end
```

And I'd like to know how to do incremented_integer in ruby or if there's a better solution rather than inserting an integer to check the position value, like key_position that would be great!

```
def check_switch(object_class)
  return $global_switch[ht[object_class].key_position]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something below using [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
CertainParentClass.decendants.each_with_index do |childrens,ind|
  ht[childrens] << ind # ind will increment with each pass by 1 default.
end
```

In case of `#each_with_index`, `ind` value will bet set as `0` by default. Now if you want to set it with other numbers rather than `0`, use [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index). Like below

```
CertainParentClass.decendants.each.with_index(2) do |childrens,ind|
  ht[childrens] << ind # ind will increment with each pass by 1 default.
end
```

I passed `2` as initial argument, which is the first `ind` value in the `with_index(2)` method, you can change it as per your need

Comment: Woah, that's great. But what if I added another keys into the hash table? Would the each_with_index still work?

Comment: @user3163916 I didn't get you.. :(

Comment: for example, after doing the CertainParentClass.decendants.each.with_index, I would like to do the same process, but with different parent class, what should I add to the argument of with_index so that it would start with the latest indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modified iterator [`:with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) of `Enumerable` module, which added index number to the end of block argument list, do as follows:

```
CertainParentClass.decendants.each.with_index do |child, index|
   ht[ childrens ] << index
end
```

And of couse you can modify not only `:each` iterator method, but a method, which returns modified, or non modified enumerable. Those methods are `:map`, `:reject`, `:select`.

Comment: Thank you for help! But I couldn't find :with_index in Enumerable module... Do you have a link for it?

Comment: @user3163916 see my answer - I linked it. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index

Comment: Nvm, found it. Thanks!